# How can i create a crunchy exterior with and airy interior donut?

Tags: doughnuts

I am attempting to make a donut that is crunchy on the outside and airy and lite on the inside with simple ingredients (yeast, flour, water, sugar.) I have tried different variations (+/- flour, +/- water, different oils) but no luck.  What should I add or add more/less of to accomplish this?

Comment: You are frying in oil?

Comment: You should edit your question to include a particular, precise recipe you tried which didn't give you the results you were looking for. Otherwise, there's no frame of reference to work from.

Comment: crunchy...like crusty bread?  ...or crispy...like a potato chip?  Can you better describe the texture you are going for?

Comment: I was attempting to make a Greek donut I recently had on holiday when visiting Europe this past summer.  I used 1tbsp instant yeast, 1cup flour, 3/4cup warm water, 1tsp sugar.  Fried at 375degree.  I am looking for a crunchy shell with an airy not doughy and chewing interior.

Comment: Are you trying to make these: https://www.mygreekdish.com/recipe/loukoumades/ ?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I am attempting to make

Comment: However the recipe I have does not include milk and I’d like to avoid it. I guess my question really is; what adjustments to the ingredients I am using would make them airy inside and crunchy outside?

Comment: If I increase the amount of yeast will that give me the Airy, light interior?